# Rails mailer url_for absolute url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Rails 3.2

I am attempting to add a url to a mailer which links to a user's website.
Here is the link that I have at the moment:

```
<%= link_to "Visit our website", url_for(:host => @dealer.stores.first.website) %>
```

However, `/assets` is getting appended to the path once the url is generated.
Here's the generated URL:

```
http://www.foo.com/assets
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening and/or how I can prevent `/assets` from being added on?

Comment: Which value contains `@dealer.stores.first.website`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; but `@dealer` is defined in the mailer (in this case `customer_mailer.rb` file).

Comment: Can you inspect that value? `<% Rails.logger.info @dealer.stories.first.website.inspect %>`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I suppose I was going about this the wrong way. I was able to get it working like so:

```
<%= link_to "Visit our website", "http://#{@dealer.stores.first.website}" %>
```